# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'MyApp' is using version 1.1.51. Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just upgraded my Gradle Plugin and I'm now getting This error:

ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'MyProject' is using version 1.1.51.
Affected Modules: app.

This prompt to upgrade came when I moved from an older version of android studio to a new one

Comment: you have to upgrade your gradle version

Comment: show your gadle code

Comment: @warl0ck I just started getting the error when I upgraded. Before the upgrade everything was working fine

Comment: @Hanzala from which gradle file should I send ?

Comment: both for app and for module

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fCL63vGh and https://pastebin.com/aR3bAUaY

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it. Just changed Kotlin version to 1.2.51 in Gradle and it worked perfectly.

[image: configuration settings in android studio]